# RuntimeError: Working outside of application context in Flask while adding a new user manually:

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, flask

I want to create a new user (called `u`) for my Flask app manualy using SQLite, but right after I write the line `db.session.add(u)`, I get this error:

> RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
with `app.app_context()`. See the documentation for more information.

What am doing wrong?

p.s: I'm doing the project millimeter by millimeter exactly like the Miguel Grinberg's Flask tutorial (page 79 for reference).

I tried adding:

```py
def create_app():
  with app.app_context():
    init_db()

return app
```

to my `__init__` sheet and it still didn't work.